# New touring bike components

Tags: shimano, touring-bikes

I'm buying a new touring bike. I need an opinion on some of the parts.

- Crankset: Shimano XT FC-M770
- Cassette: Shimano XT CS-M770
- Rear Derailleur: Shimano XT M772 SGS
- Front Derailleur: Shimano XT M770 Top Swing 9sp Front Mech
- Chain: Shimano Dura-Ace/XTR 7701 9 Speed Chain

Are these compatible with each other? I can get a good deal on these components.

I'm also looking for 9 speed compatible bar-end shifters. Any recommendations?

Comment: Are you buying a bike with these components, upgrading a new bike or building a bike with the intention of using these components?

Comment: I am a little curious as to why you don't just buy a ready-made touring bike.  Generally the components will be well-matched to each other and the frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are all compatible. Generally speaking, 9-speed Shimano mountain bike parts are compatible with one another without. If there's an exception to that rule, I've never seen it.

One thing you might want to check is that your frame will be compatible with your top swing front derailleur. It's fairly likely that your touring frame is set up for bottom pull. If it is, you're better off getting a bottom-pull derailleur. There may be a way to make it work, but if so it's out of my realm of experience. And if you're getting new parts anyway it's just easier not to mess with it.

As for the shifters, just make sure that they're compatible with a 9-speed shimano mountain bike derailleur. You won't get good shifting out of one that's designed for road derailleurs.

As far as opinions and/or suggestions about what brand or model to buy specifically, those are generally considered off-topic per the [FAQ](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: For shifters, you might consider friction shifters (bar end, stem mount, downtube mount...). They're always compatible and touring bikes generally spec them.